Function parameter type collapsing to any when using recursive conditional type
This is a follow-up of an issue posted in the Typescript project on Github.
Joe Calzaretta (@jcalz) kindly gave me a solution for my first recursive conditional type problem but I'm now facing another issue with a function parameter becoming of type any instead of the expected type.
Here is an excerpt of the code showing the issue:
type ValidationContext<ValueType> = { value: ValueType }
type Constraint<ValueType, ConstraintType> =
    ConstraintType | ((context: ValidationContext<ValueType>) => ConstraintType)

type StringType = string | null | undefined
type StringConstraints = {
    required?: Constraint<StringType, boolean>,
    length?: Constraint<StringType, number>
}
type StringSchema = readonly ["string", StringConstraints]

type ObjectType = object | null | undefined
type ObjectConstraints = { required?: Constraint<ObjectType, boolean> } | undefined
type ObjectSchema<T extends ObjectType> =
    readonly ["object", ObjectConstraints, { [P in keyof T]: SchemaFor<T[P]> }]


type SchemaFor<T> =
    [T] extends [StringType] ? StringSchema :
    [T] extends [ObjectType] ? ObjectSchema<T> :
    never

type AnySchema = StringSchema | ObjectSchema<ObjectType>

type ValidateSchema<T> =
    T extends StringSchema ? StringSchema :
    T extends readonly ["object", ObjectConstraints, infer S extends ObjectType] ?
        readonly ["object", ObjectConstraints, { [K in keyof S]: ValidateSchema<S[K]> }] :
    never

function validate<const T extends AnySchema>(schema: T & ValidateSchema<T>, value: any) {
    return []
}

// Ok: context: ValidationContext<StringType>
validate(["string", { length: (context) => 1 }], null)

// Error: Parameter 'context' implicitly has an 'any' type
validate(["string", { required: (context) => true }], null)

// Error: Parameter 'context' implicitly has an 'any' type
validate(["object", { required: (context) => true }, {}], null)

// Ok:
//     required: true | (true & ((context: ValidationContext<ObjectType>) => boolean))
// and
//     required: true | (true & ((context: ValidationContext<StringType>) => boolean))
validate(["object", { required: true }, {
    name: ["string", { required: true }],
}], null)

While the type of the context parameter is correctly inferred in the first validate call (ie: ValidationContext<StringType> for the length constraint), it becomes any as soon as I use the constraint name required shared by StringConstraints and ObjectConstraints.
Can anybody help me get the expected ValidationContext<...> types?
Here is a typescript playground link with the code above.

EDIT (simplified version, playground link here):
type StringSchema = ["string", { required?: (value: string) => boolean }]
type NumberSchema = ["number", { required?: (value: number) => boolean }]

type AnySchema = StringSchema | NumberSchema

function validate(schema: AnySchema) {
    return schema[0]
}

// Error: Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type
validate(["string", { required: (value) => true }])

// Error: Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type
validate(["number", { required: (value) => true }])

If I use schema definitions with objects (playground), the problem vanished:
type StringSchema = {
    kind: "string"
    constraints: { required?: (value: string) => boolean }
}
type NumberSchema = {
    kind: "number"
    constraints: { required?: (value: number) => boolean }
}

type AnySchema = StringSchema | NumberSchema

function validate(schema: AnySchema) {
    return schema.kind
}

// Ok: (parameter) value: string
validate({ kind: "string", constraints: { required: (value) => true } })

// Ok: (parameter) value: number
validate({ kind: "number", constraints: { required: (value) => true } })

So we can be pretty sure it is related to the use of tuples.
Should I fill a bug on Github?
I'll try to provide a PR if I can understand how to set up a custom version of tsc.

This is fairly complicated; could you reduce this to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue? My guess here is that this is going to just be a TS limitation/bug, as described in ms/TS#55632 and the workaround is either annotate your callback params or refactor away from tuples. Or you can submit a PR fixing the bug to TS since it's "help wanted". But without a smaller [mre] I can't be sure. How should we proceed here?

see prev comment. Do you agree that this minimal example demonstrates what you're running into? (compare the bad behavior for array literals with the good behavior for object literals). If so then we've found your issue. If not then please [edit] to make it clearer what your problem is.

@jcalz I'll try to simplify my code and to find out what are the key elements causing this issue (probably related to tuples). I would also love to provide a PR, but I need time to dig into the Typescript code. Thanks again!

@jcalz see the simplified code in the EDIT section

Okay, so then this is indeed the same issue as ms/TS#55632 and I'll write up an answer to that effect.  Note that the question seems to have the skeleton of an answer in it as an edit... that would best belong in the answer only. But it's fine either way.

As stated in the "EDIT" section above, a workaround is to give up on tuples and use object types and literals instead.
But the best option would be to fix the microsoft/TypeScript#55632 issue: here is a PR microsoft/TypeScript#60434 that would give a proper solution to this problem if merged.

This is already a known TypeScript bug, reported at microsoft/TypeScript#55632. TypeScript doesn't currently contextually type callback parameters for discriminated unions of tuple types in array literals.  Indeed if you switch from arrays to objects, you get the contextual typing you expect.  For now the workarounds are either to give up on contextual typing (and just annotate your callback parameters or to give up on tuples (and use objects instead).
This bug is labeled as "Help Wanted", so the TS team welcomes pull requests to fix it.  The  interested reader who wants to see this fixed instead of working around it might decide to submit a PR that fixes it instead.

I'm going to work on a PR, I'll let you know if I can find a solution. Thanks for your help. BTW: I don't get what you mean by "to give up on contextual typing and just annotate your callback parameters". My callback parameters are annotated (string / number). Do you mean I should annotate them with a common type (any)?

I mean (value: number)=>true instead of value=>true. The actual callbacks themselves.

see my PR here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/60434.
